# Remove letter “e” in the end of each word Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Need help. Remove letter “e” in the end of each word if word length > 1.
I have tried to do it via strig split and toCharArray, but I can't convert array after removing to string.
Thank you in advance.

```
public class RemoveE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "like row lounge dude top";
        String[] words = str.split("\\s|[,.;:]");
        for (String subStr : words) {
            if (subStr.endsWith("e"))
                subStr = subStr.substring(0, subStr.length() - 1);
            String finalString = new String(subStr);
            System.out.println(finalString);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Go back to a sentence of word you mean ?

Comment: @shmosel - what happened to your correct answer that you posted in your comment?  Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

It would be much simpler if you do it via regex like this

```
finalString = str.replaceAll("e\\b", "");
```

This is giving following output:

```
lik row loung dud top
```

*PS: This solution assumes that you would like to drop even a single `e` in string since in the question, we're using `if (subStr.endsWith("e"))` which will also remove a single `e` in the String.*

Comment: Maybe give him some details about the regex ? And also explain hiw how to concat again, because with this he won't know how leanr how to

Comment: `if word.length > 1` consider `System.out.println("e".replaceAll("e\\b", "l"));`

Comment: @ScaryWombat well OP himself is using condition `if (subStr.endsWith("e"))` which returns true for a single `e` in a word, maybe he himself wants a single `e` to be replaced as well.

Comment: Huh? The OP is asking for help because his code is **not** working - why provide more code that is **not** working?

Answer (score 3):

For your code, all the splitting and `if` conditions are right, all you need to do is add the `subStr` to `finalString` when process is completed. I've re-arranged 3 lines from your code, you can find explanation within comments:

```
public class RemoveE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "like row lounge dude top";
        String[] words = str.split("\\s|[,.;:]");

        String finalString = ""; // Bring the declaration outside of for loop

        for (String subStr : words) {
            if (subStr.endsWith("e"))
                subStr = subStr.substring(0, subStr.length() - 1);
            finalString += subStr + " "; // Add the substring and a whitespace to substring and add it to finalString to create the sentence again
        }

        System.out.println(finalString); // Print the String outside of final `for` loop
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
lik row loung dud top
```

Comment: Can we make finalString a StringBuilder ?

Comment: @DebapriyaBiswas yes that would be a plus.

Answer (score 3):

Raman's first answer provides a good start for a solution with a regular expression. However to ensure that that it only drops the `e` if the word itself has more than one character, you can add a negative lookbehind to ensure that there is no word boundary *immediately before* the letter `e` with `(?<!\\b)` :

```
String str = "like row lounge dude top e";

String replaced = str.replaceAll("(?<!\\b)e\\b", "");

System.out.println("Replaced: " + replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is without `regex`. Adding this as reference as this may be helpful too in future.

I guess, explanation is not needed as a new `char` array is created and simple for-loop is used to iterate through the input string and keep the valid `char` in the new `char` array in appropriate position by checking the conditions.

```
public class RemoveE {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "like row lounge dude top";
        char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();

        int size = str.length();
        int temp = 0;

        char[] newStringChars = new char[size];
        String newString = null;
        newStringChars[0] = strChars[0];


        for(int i=1; i<size; i++) {
            if(!(strChars[i] == 'e' && strChars[i+1] == ' ')) {
                temp++;
                newStringChars[temp] = strChars[i];
            }
            else if(strChars[i] == 'e' && strChars[i+1] == ' ' && strChars[i-1] == ' ') {
                temp++;
                newStringChars[temp] = strChars[i];
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        newString = String.valueOf(newStringChars);
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
}
```

> For `String str = "like row lounge dude top";` output is:
>
> ```
> lik row loung dud top
> ```

AND

> For `String str = "like row e lounge dude top";` (only one `e` present
>   in a word, i.e. not `word length > 1` as mentioned in the question),
>   output is:
>
> ```
> lik row e loung dud top
> ```